# force compiler to generate whole class template

Tags: c++, templates

how can I force compiler, to generate whole class template? not just methods I use? I am sure I read it in template complete guide book, but I can not find it. It was one-line statement.

I am not able to ask google the right question.

Thank you!

Comment: I don't get the question... Give some example maybe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can explicitly instantiate a class template with something like this:

```
template class Foo<Argument1,Argument2>;
```

Comment: This method is the basis for [extern templates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x#Extern_template) in C++0x